# Overriding calls from kernel32

Tags: c++, dll, overloading, dll-injection, overriding

A executable file opens a *file* from the disk likely using `CreateFileA`

What I want to do is to override the call from `kernel32.dll`

and give the it `stdin/stdout HANDLE`

What I can do:

- Give it my `winmm.dll` because it loads `timeGetTime` from it to get time

When I tried to override CreateFileA call in my DLL, the compiler just don't let me compile because kernel32.dll already have its reference

```
winmm.cpp(56): warning C4273: 'CreateFileA': inconsistent dll linkage
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\fileapi.h(122): note: see previous definition of 'CreateFileA'
```

Is there way to make the DLL I made to make it do that?

PS: I don't know much assembly but here is the disassembly when the program is scanning for the file I gave as parameter

[image]

[image]

Comment: use proper c++ and pass a `std::basic_ostream`
 to your code... now you can write to a file, stdout or a string...

Comment: I don't the source of the file. I just want to pass stdin/stdout handle to it to make a wrapper.

Comment: Intercepting another process's calls into the OS is an advanced topic.  This question is probably beyond the scope of the Stack Overflow format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try API hooking instead. Check out these links-

https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/160-apihooks

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed